# Is there a way to call abort() on a jQuery Autocomplete AJAX call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to build a "cancel" link to a jQuery autocomplete field for a large database call. In case it takes too long, it'd be nice if there were a way to cancel the AJAX call that the autocomplete() function makes.

I know the .abort() function exists for the .ajax() call, but is there some analogous call for a function like autocomplete() that encapsulates an AJAX call? Thanks.